# IronRuby doesn't recognize 'rake' - I'm getting undefined method `rake' for main:Object, how to fix?

Tags: ruby, .net-4.0, rubygems, ironruby

Just installed IronRuby 1.1. I'm trying to take a look at rake and albacore.  After installing ironruby, I am able to hit a command prompt by typing ir, and I am able to do simple puts, but when I try to run rake, I get the error

```
undefined method `rake' for main:Object
```

How do I resolve this?  Any ideas?

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: @Ed Swangren: [IronRuby isn't dead](http://www.rubyinside.com/microsoft-tires-of-ironruby-jimmy-schementi-jumps-ship-3639.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rake` is an executable Ruby script that you call from the Windows command line, not a Ruby method that you call from IRb.